# How to make RedirectToAction with multiple parameters and route as UFL

Tags: c#, .net

I'm having a bit of a trouble with routing in .net.

When I'm making a `RedirectToAction` with the following code:

```
return RedirectToAction("Edit", "Add", new { id = newId, someVal = newSomeVal });
```

and the following `MapRoute`:

```
context.MapRoute(  
    "EditStuff",  
    "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}/{someVal}",  
    new { controller = "Edit", action = "Add", id = @"\d+", someVal = @"\d+" }  
);
```

I get redirected to an URL that has the someVal parameter delimited by `?` instead of `/`, so: `http://localhost:60733/Admin/Edit/Add/43?someVal=1`
instead of
`http://localhost:60733/Admin/Edit/Add/43/1`

Both links work if I access them directly.

Can someone shine some light on this issue?

Many thanks!

Comment: Do you have any more routes mapped? It might be that another route is picking up the route before that one. Try RouteDebugger if you have problems debugging routes :) http://haacked.com/archive/2011/04/12/routedebugger-2.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I tried using the RouteDebugger and found out that 2 routes matched for that redirect (one without the `someVal`), so I just made RedirectToRoute instead.

Comment: Glad you solved your issue.